# Group by and also order by?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Two tables: 
Topics
Comments (There is a Topic field, so I know in which topic the comment is)

And I want to get only the newest comment in each topic (highest value in Date field) and then order the topics in that way.

Query I've tried:

```
SELECT User, Topic, Date 
FROM   Comments 
GROUP BY Topic 
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Comment: SELECT User,Topic,Date FROM Comments GROUP BY Topic ORDER BY Date DESC

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason it select the first comments of the topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a row if no other row with same topic has a later date.

```
SELECT User, Topic, Date 
FROM   Comments c1
where not exists (select 1 from Comments c2
                  where c2.topic = c1.topic
                    and c2.date > c1.date)
order by date desc
```

Comment: Thanks, yours fixed it, for some reason ajmedway's gave the wrong user.

Comment: MySQL is a bit unpredictable if you don't follow the general group by rule. (If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.)

Comment: @Tudvari hey, just improved my query, could you just try it to see if it work? Curious :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, improved answer:

```
SELECT `User`,
       temp.`Topic`,
       temp.`Date`
FROM (
       SELECT `Topic`,
              MAX(`Date`) `Date`
       FROM `Comments`
       GROUP BY `Topic`
       ORDER BY MAX(`Date`) DESC
      ) temp
INNER JOIN `Comments`
     USING (`Topic`, `Date`)
```

Comment: Results: https://i.gyazo.com/6a596068f3d6412679dbcf7d0b30a798.png
Columns: User, Topic, Date

Comment: @Tudvari so the data is as expected? Would you mind upvoting my answer if so? Thanks :)

Comment: No it isn't. In Topic 1 there are 7 Comments, and your query select 4 of them for some reason. :(

Comment: @Tudvari Ah!! Got you, sorry was doing the `GROUP BY` on the user, could you refresh and try my answer again? thanks :)

Comment: You can remove the ORDER BY from the sub-query, it makes no difference.